# how to send multi video in udp protocol with in single ip/port?

Tags: networking, ffmpeg, video, udp, pid

According to the ffmpeg documentation using UDP protocol
i need send multi input to local network in single IP/Port and received from VLC Player each video can choose with Program number and show it !

The code I'm using:

`ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i video1.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -re -i video2.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -re -i video3.mp4 -map 0  -mpegts_service_id 0x009A -map 1  -mpegts_service_id 0x009C -metadata service_name='A1' -map 2  -mpegts_service_id 0x009E -metadata service_name='B2' -c copy -mpegts_pmt_start_pid 0x02BF -mpegts_start_pid 0x0271 -mpegts_transport_stream_id 0x0279  -mpegts_original_network_id 0x005F -tables_version 0 -f mpegts udp://234.5.5.6:5006`

Actually, I need something like this image:

[image]